# I am not able to build post comment section.The entry that I am making in database is not visible on frontend

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create a comment feature on my post .At initial level I just made a table comment and post. And made a manual entry in comment table through admin side but even that comments are also not available on the post(frontend).

It looks like the image given below:

[image: It looks like the image given below]

My models.py for post and comment looks like this:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post=models.ForeignKey(MyPost,related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body=models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.post.subject,self.name)

class MyPost(models.Model):
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="images\\", null=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    msg = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    cr_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(to=MyProfile, on_delete=CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
    return "%s" % self.subject
```

I added this in html page:

```
 <h2> Comments</h2>
        <br/>
        {% if not post.comments.all %}
            No comments yet...<a href="#">
            Add one</a>
        {% else %}
        <a href="#">Add Comment</a>
        <br/>
            {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
                <strong>
                    {{ comment.name }} -
                    {{ comment.date_added }}
                </strong>
                <br/>
                {{ comment.body }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
<br/>
```

Comment: You mean... data is showing on admin page but not on your custom page??

Comment: Can you share your view code?

Comment: actually intially I had manually entered a comment in my Comment Table and was expecting it to see it on my custom page but it was not visible not there and could only see the"No comments yet......add one" which is my if statement.

Comment: but since i had made a comment on a post i was expecting it to get viewed under that post